# Specflow 3.1 throwing test failure message despite of catch block

Tags: specflow

Test code looks something like this

```cs
if (table.ContainsColumn("DecisionGroupOptionId"))
{
    foreach (var tableRow in table.Rows)
    {
        try
        {
            var name = tableRow["DecisionGroupOptionId"];
            var code = _catalogLookupContext.DecisionGroupOptions.FindIdByName(name);
            tableRow["DecisionGroupOptionId"] = code;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            //don't fail
        }
    }
}

public virtual string FindIdByName(string name)
{
    var item = _list.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == name);
    Assert.That(item, Is.Not.Null, "ID lookup by the name '{0}' failed. No such name exists in the map.", name);
    return item.Id;
}
```

Testlog output :

```
   Failed : org.test.Test.Silverthread.test1
    ID lookup by the name '' failed. No such name exists in the map.
    Expected: not null
    But was:  null
    at org.test.Test.SilverThread.FindIdByName(String name) in IdLookup.cs:line 
    160
```

The testlog shows failure if 'name' is null.
Isnt this not supposed to show failure as there is catch block? Please help.

Test project uses assemblies like below

```
 [SpecFlow]   SpecFlow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41
 [SpecFlow]   TechTalk.SpecFlow, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41
 [SpecFlow]   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Generator, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41
 [SpecFlow]   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Utils, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41
 [SpecFlow]   TechTalk.SpecFlow.Parser, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41
 [SpecFlow]   TechTalk.SpecFlow.NUnit.Generator.SpecFlowPlugin, Version=3.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0778194805d6db41
```

Comment: "_testlog shows failure_" - what failure? Quote the full error. "_Isnt this not supposed to show failure as there is catch block?_" - that depends on what/if the assembly throws, doesn't it? Does it document that at all?

Comment: @underscore_d thanks. updated testlog. The Assert line throws the exception when condition doesnt match. And No, the exception is not documented.

Comment: So, then, it seems that simply the function `FindIdByName` does not throw if you give it a null, and therefore you have nothing to catch. You would need to handle that case in a different way. Is that your function? Then you can make it throw and catch that. Etc., etc.,

Comment: i think the Exception class used here is super class which should catch all types of exceptions?

Comment: Again, where is an exception being thrown from? You said the library doesn't. Your function doesn't seem to, because `Assert.That()` is an assertion, not something that throws if it fails (if it did, how could one assert that some other exception go thrown?). So I don't see how there is anything to catch, yet.